# WooCommerce - Hook after Loading Variation in Admin Edit page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In Product's Edit page, when we click Variations, we will see AJAX loading for all of its variations.

Is there a Hook for when it finished?

I want to run a script to add some "at-a-glance" information on each Toggle Header. For example "Sold Out" label when the variation has 0 stock.

Thanks

Comment: It is javascript so you are looking for a callback not a hook as such... you could maybe search the variations javascript to find a callback...

Comment: @majick Unless I'm mistaken, do I need to edit the WooCommerce source file if I want to add callback in that Javascript? **EDIT** it seems there's event listener as answered below. so I'm indeed mistaken

Comment: yep that looks like the droid - err - i mean callback you are looking for.

Comment: Do not edit plugin files and or WordPress core files, your changes will be lost in updates, it's bad practice. Always look for hooks, actions/filters or events (if working with JS), there's almost always a way to solve a problem without ever having to resort to editing core files of any plugin. Even at a worse-case scenario, you can use `$.ajaxStop()` if there was no such event and listen/observe for DOM mutations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php` there is a method on the `WC_AJAX` class responsible for loading variations called `load_variations`, it contains only one hook, which is a filter, named `woocommerce_ajax_admin_get_variations_args` which fires early in the method.

However if you are looking for something client side, then `woocommerce/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-product-variation.js` triggers an event on the success callback of the `load_variations` function named `woocommerce_variations_loaded`.

Therefore if you are looking to fire subsequent actions using JS, then:

```
$(document).on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function(event) {
    //your code here...
});
```

Or you can try binding to the element in which the trigger is executed upon:

```
$('#woocommerce-product-data').on('woocommerce_variations_loaded', function(event) {
    //your code here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one (`$("#woocommerce-product-data")...`) works great! I wish WooCommerce is better documented :(